# not able to connect to the teradata aws instance via jdbc

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jdbc, teradata, putty

I am not able to connect to Teradata aws instance through either JDBC drivers in Java nor Teradata studio. however i am able to connect through putty and able to query the database in bteq.

whenn i am connecting through java code, it says connection time out and when i am trying through Teradata studio it says, ping failed(login time out).

AWS has Teradata Database Developer -singlenode -15-10-01-06-1.
Teradata studio version:16.0.2.201703141245

Exception that I am getting on Teradatastudio:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 16.00.00.23] [Error 1000] [SQLState 08S01] Login failure for Packet receive Sat Mar 25 01:33:12 IST 2017 socket orig=52.26.246.236 local=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:43787 remote=/XX.XX.XXX.XXX:XX keepalive=unavailable nodelay=unavailable receive=unavailable send=unavailable linger=unavailable traffic=unavailable concurrent=3 contimeout=10000 conwait=1000 connecttime=329 connecttotaltime=332 connectattempts=1 connectfailures=0 reconnectattempts=0 recoverable=false redrive=false failurecache={ec2-35-163-156-117.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/35.163.156.117:1025=Wed Mar 22 14:32:40 IST 2017, /52.26.246.236:1025=Fri Mar 24 12:25:13 IST 2017, /172.31.10.129:22=Fri Mar 24 12:24:19 IST 2017, ec2-50-112-137-170.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/50.112.137.170:1025=Thu Mar 23 04:27:23 IST 2017, /34.208.105.91:1025=Fri Mar 24 08:38:17 IST 2017, /172.31.10.129:1025=Fri Mar 24 12:23:19 IST 2017, /34.208.210.30:1025=Thu Mar 23 04:26:13 IST 2017} cid=17a34262 sess=0 java.net.SocketException: Connection reset   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF.read(TDNetworkIOIF.java:734)   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDPacketStream.readStream(TDPacketStream.java:768)   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.GenericLogonController.run(GenericLogonController.java:104)   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.<init>(TDSession.java:209)   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_Connection.<init>(JDK6_SQL_Connection.java:36)   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6ConnectionFactory.constructSQLConnection(JDK6ConnectionFactory.java:25)   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:179)   at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:169)   at com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver.doConnect(TeraDriver.java:235)   at com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver.connect(TeraDriver.java:161)   at com.teradata.datatools.dtp.connectivity.db.teradata.TeradataJDBCConnection.makeConnection(TeradataJDBCConnection.java:280)   at com.teradata.datatools.dtp.connectivity.db.teradata.TeradataJDBCConnection.createConnection(TeradataJDBCConnection.java:122)   at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)   at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)   at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)   at com.teradata.datatools.dtp.connectivity.db.teradata.TeradataPingFactory.createConnection(TeradataPingFactory.java:36)   at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)   at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)   at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)   at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)  
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:95)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:70)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeIoJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:208)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorAnalyzer.analyzeIoError(ErrorAnalyzer.java:59)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF.read(TDNetworkIOIF.java:931)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDPacketStream.readStream(TDPacketStream.java:768)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.GenericLogonController.run(GenericLogonController.java:104)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.<init>(TDSession.java:209)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_Connection.<init>(JDK6_SQL_Connection.java:36)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6ConnectionFactory.constructSQLConnection(JDK6ConnectionFactory.java:25)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:179)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:169)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver.doConnect(TeraDriver.java:235)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver.connect(TeraDriver.java:161)
    at com.teradata.datatools.dtp.connectivity.db.teradata.TeradataJDBCConnection.makeConnection(TeradataJDBCConnection.java:280)
    at com.teradata.datatools.dtp.connectivity.db.teradata.TeradataJDBCConnection.createConnection(TeradataJDBCConnection.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)
    at com.teradata.datatools.dtp.connectivity.db.teradata.TeradataPingFactory.createConnection(TeradataPingFactory.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF.read(TDNetworkIOIF.java:734)
    ... 20 more
```

please let me know what could be the gap here and let me know if you need any further details.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: what error message it gives?

Comment: if you are can ping the server. and you don't have a proxy  check the ip address or the port

Comment: Sounds like a network connectivity issue...

Comment: after opening custom icmp rule with echo request, its worked..